# Is there a simple way to remove ColdFusion comments from a file?

Tags: coldfusion, comments

Is there a quick way to remove all of the comments from a Coldfusion File? I have to work on a file that is mostly comments (especially comments of old non-functional code), and I'd like to create a temporary version with no comments and functional code only.

I generally use Notepad++ to edit CFM files, but I also have ColdFusion Studio.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do those editors have a find and replace that supports regex? It'd be pretty easy to do with that I'd think.

Comment: see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804951/regex-to-remove-comments-in-xml-file-in-eclipse-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CFML you can do it with a quick regex. This only works with CFML tag based comments, not script ones.

```
<cfset contents = fileRead(expandPath("./test2.cfm"))>
<cfset noComments = rereplace(contents, "<!---.*?--->", "", "all")>
<cfoutput>
#htmlCodeFormat(noComments)#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: This will break if you have nested comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
You need a multirow regex find/replace. Eclipse let's you do it with:(?s)<!---(.*?)--->

Alternately, you can..
Open http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
Enter <!---(.*\r)*---> into first box.
Press Replace Tab.
Copy/Paste your file's code into first text area.
Second text area will contain filtered code.

Works for CFML comments, you can modify regex to work for script comments.n
```

Comment: Yeah, multi-line stuff is a bugger. Got an example? I'll run something up.

Comment: I ran a couple of tests. (?s)<!---(.*?)---> works well in Sublime and CFBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a cfm script to parse the entire .cfm file as a text file. (Using cffile or a java file method).

Then slip in a simple regex to remove anything between

There are several good regex examples that will remove particular tags from html that should work great for this.

Here's a regex I used to remove the first   in some code that was wrapping itself around some XML I was rendering.   It should be pretty close to what you need to remove all of the comments.

<\/?div[^>]*?>

Best of luck!