# Remove comments in XML android

Tags: java, android, xml, comments

I'm working in eclipse and I would like to remove all the commentaries in my XML file in my code.

When there is no comment in my XML file, my application works. But as soon as I have any commentary in my XML file, my application stop working.

My question is : in android java, is there any way to remove with a code all the commentaries in my XML file?

I searched some keywords on google, but i don't find anything for java, only for C# or VB.
In those languages, they use something like "node" (I didn't really understood how it was working)

I join an example of XML file where there is the type of comment that I want to remove.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<pma_xml_export version="1.0" xmlns:pma="http://www.phpmyadmin.net/some_doc_url/">



    <database name="mvc">

       <!-- XML commentaries that i want to remove -->

        <table name="hrd">
            <column name="No_HRD">1</column>
            <column name="Nom_HRD">H?tel Fleuritel</column>
            <column name="Rue_HRD"> 1 Bd Jean Delautre</column>
            <column name="CP_HRD">08000</column>
            <column name="Ville_HRD"> Charleville-M?zi?re</column>
            <column name="Tel_HRD"> 03 24 37</column>
            <column name="Fax_HRD">03 24 37 5</column>
            <column name="Email_HRD"> </column>
            <column name="Image_HRD">1</column>
            <column name="Site_HRD"> http://www.hotel-fleuritel.com</column>
            <column name="No_Categorie_HRD">H</column>
            <column name="No_Ville_HRD">1</column>
        </table>

        <!-- XML commentaries that i want to remove -->

        <table name="hrd">
            <column name="No_HRD">2</column>
            <column name="Nom_HRD">Premi?re Classe CHARLEVILLE-MEZIERES</column>
            <column name="Rue_HRD">Route de la Francheville ZAC Du MOULIN-LE-BLANC</column>
            <column name="CP_HRD">08000</column>
            <column name="Ville_HRD"> Charleville-M?zi?re</column>
            <column name="Tel_HRD">08 92 70 7</column>
            <column name="Fax_HRD"> 03 24 37</column>
            <column name="Email_HRD">charlevillemezieres@premiereclasse.fr </column>
            <column name="Image_HRD">3</column>
            <column name="Site_HRD">http://www.premiere-classe-charleville-mezieres.fr</column>
            <column name="No_Categorie_HRD">H</column>
            <column name="No_Ville_HRD">1</column>
        <!-- XML commentaries that i want to remove -->
        </table>
        <!-- XML commentaries that i want to remove -->
    </database>
</pma_xml_export>
```

Comment: A previous post talks about a regex that can remove xml comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804951/regex-to-remove-comments-in-xml-file-in-eclipse-java

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sadly, this isn't what i search ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to get them out. You can just skip them. It is explained on the android development site. On [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) page.

If you go to the "read the feed" part you'll see that it will just skip it if it doesn't recognise it as a tag. If you do it this way it will just skip the commentary. I implemented this in my own project recently. So I can confirm that it works.